# API Import Export tool not creating custom sequences

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 APIM2.0 and enabled the import/export tool (api-import-export-2.0.0-v0). I am able to export the API ok. My API has got custom input and output sequence attached to it. I can see the custom sequences in the exported zip file. But when I import the same into any other environment the APIs are created properly but the custom sequences neither created nor attached to the imported APIs. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fixed by now. Please get latest tool (v2) from https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment

Comment: Did a fresh export and import with this version now. Still didn't work :(

Comment: Can you try with this version?
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment

Comment: But my APIM is 2.0. Isn't this version of tool for APIM 2.1 only?

Comment: I still tried to publish the APIs without custom sequences. I am seeing few exceptions now. `ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil} - Issue is in accessing the Registry` and `TID[-1234] [AM] [2017-06-06 14:41:08,766] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager} - Error in updating the sequence at the Gateway org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getCustomSequence(APIUtil.java:3757) org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.deployInSequence(APIGatewayManager.java:371) ` and few more

Comment: Just try 2.1.0 one. There shouldn't be a big difference.

Comment: Tried now. 2.1.0 export is not producing a valid zip file from API Manager 2.0

Comment: Workaround to this is - Upload the custom in & out sequences into the registry under the path `/_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/in & /_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/out` respectively and then import the zip file. Now imported APIs will have the custom sequences. Looks like import tool is unable to create files in the registry for some reason.